# How to create more form fields by using javascript and then passing values to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic

Hi I'd like to make it so that the user can click a "upload more files" button to create an additional file upload form field and they can also click another button called "add more names" to create an additional "input type='text'" form field.

There should be a limit on how many file upload or text fields that can be created using their respective buttons. For example, there should be a max number of 5 file upload fields and a max number of 5 text fields.

After the user clicks the "submit" button, the script will record the total number of file upload and text form fields and pass those numbers to PHP. For example, if there are 5 file upload and 5 text form fields, the variable $numfiles will record the number of file upload fields and the variable $numtext will record the number of text fields.

A sample code would be great, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like you've tried anything... you should google about it.

Comment: jquery: `$('#yourtextfieldplace').append('<input type="text" name="somename[]">');`  is the very simplest method. Doing the "no more than 5" business is a bit more work, but also trivial.

Comment: This looks more like a ScriptLance job than a StackOverflow question

Comment: How much money u are paying.. Lemme know, i will provide the code.:-P Do some homwwork first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
var totalFields = <?=$total_fields?>;
var currentFields = 0;

var addMode = document.getElementById('addMore');
var form = docuement.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

addMore.onclick = function() {
   if (currentFields >= totalFields) {
      return false;
   }
   var newField = document.createElement('input');
   newField.setAttribute('type', 'file');
   newField.setAttribute('name', 'file'+currentFields);
   form.appendChild(newField);
   currentFields++
}
```

and then

```
<?
   foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
      // i guess you know what you should do
   }
?>
```

not tested ... just for example