# Saving only changed fields in a CakePHP 2.0 Form

Tags: forms, cakephp, save, field

I'm creating a CakePHP application that can have multiple users editing the same information at the same time. To prevent users from overwriting over each other's changes, I want to make it where when a user saves their form, it only saves the one or two fields that the user has changed.

I can't just compare the fields to the database values because those database values may actually be newer ones from other users.

Does CakePHP offer any way to only send the updated fields via POST?

Comment: Have you thought about a javascript solution?  onchange() update an array of "changedFields", then submit that and process only the fields listed?

Comment: Dave, that's what I was actually hoping to do. Honestly I'm more of an Objective-C and C++ person more than a JavaScript and PHP person so I wasn't sure how it would be implemented. The other advantage to that is that the save() command for CakePHP has a parameter for what fields should be saved (to prevent hacks). My only question then is how do I append that extra data to $this->request->data when the form submits?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269145/how-to-create-more-form-fields-by-using-javascript-and-then-passing-values-to-ph

Comment: That will work great, thank you! I thought it might be hacky to send a JS array as comma delimited data in a text field, but there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in solution. I came up with some code that works, but you would definitely want to put it into its own function so that it can be used by multiple controller actions. Also, it's not perfect. For example, it would fail on a date field since CakePHP has date fields rendered as `select`s in forms.

This is for an edit action. Original code:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
}
```

Modified code:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $originalData = unserialize(base64_decode($this->request->data['Extra']['original_data']));
        $save = $this->request->data;
        unset($save['Extra']);

        foreach ($save as $model => $modelFields) {
            if (!array_key_exists($model, $originalData)) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($modelFields as $field => $value) {
                if (!array_key_exists($field, $originalData[$model])) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($save[$model][$field] === $originalData[$model][$field]) {
                    unset($save[$model][$field]);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->User->set($save);

        if ($this->User->validates() && $this->User->save($save, false)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        $this->request->data['Extra']['original_data'] = base64_encode(serialize($this->request->data));
    }
}
```

Also, add this somewhere in the form in `edit.ctp`:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Extra.original_data');
```

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely a step in the right direction. Also, I hate the way CakePHP handles dates as three separate selects anyway, so I've laid out dates as text fields.